# Speed up creation of WebView

Tags: java, performance, javafx, webview

I'm currently creating a [WebView](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) simply with `new WebView()` but it takes more than one second (on my computer with JavaFX 11.0.2).

According to the documentation and my tests it's only possible to do this on the JavaFX-Thread:

> WebView objects must be created and accessed solely from the FX thread.

So this blocks the FX thread for quite some time. **Is there a hack/workaround/... to do this (or at least part of it) in another thread than the FX thread?**

Comment: Use [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) and use the CPU Sampler to check what is taking the time (which method). Knowing the source of a problem is the first step to solve it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is one second too long?  Opening a new browser window often takes at least that long.  Users don’t seem to mind.

Comment: Does it only take one second for the first WebView you create?

Comment: The `WebEngine` already runs in the background; reduce _percieved_ latency by listening to relevant `WebEngine` properties and displaying the result.

Comment: @Robert: That was a great idea, although it didn't bring me really closer to a solution. The time gets lost by `new WebView() -> new WebEngine() -> new WebPage() -> private native void twkInit(...)`. And all of these have to be called on the FX thread.

Comment: @VGR & codeflush.dev: Yes it only takes 1 second on the first creation. But it freezes the whole application and makes it unresponsive which is certainly not a good user experience.

Comment: If it’s only the first WebView creation that takes one second, create it in the Application.start method before showing the initial Stage.  At least that way, it will appear to contribute to startup time rather than delaying the UI.

Comment: @VGR: That's what I'm was doing. But now I try to show a launch-progressbar but I can't show any progress as it freezes when I start creating the WebView.

Comment: I’m surprised a one-second delay in a progress bar is a problem.  I’m sure we’ve all seen worse.  Perhaps you can create the WebView before even showing the progress bar?

Comment: Could you not create a `WebViewCreatorTask extends Task<WebView>` you can then plug your progress bar into the progress of the task.  You can do whatever you want to the WebView prior to adding it to the FX `A scene graph can be created and manipulated in a background thread, but when its root node is attached to any live object in the scene, that scene graph must be accessed from the JavaFX application thread.`

Comment: @kendavidson: This sounds very promising! How would I do that exactly?

Comment: I'll answer.onday when I'm at a computer if no one beats me to it. But give it a go and post your attempt.